# I am trying to get an embeded flash game to change when you click on the link using javascript?

Tags: javascript, flash, embed, src

I am not using jquery nor know how to.

Here is the html code:

```
<div class="currentgame">
<embed id="currentgame" src="" height="100%" width="100%"/>
</div>
<div class="games">
<strong>Action:</strong><a href="#" onClick="showAction(action);">+</a><a href="#" onClick="showAction2(strat);">-</a><br />
<div id="action">
<a href="#" id="brainforce" onclick="getMyID(this.id);"><img src="images/brainforce.jpg"/><b>Brainforce</b></a><img src="images/breakit.jpg"/><b>Break-it</b><img src="images/Bubble.jpg"/><b>Bubble</b><img src="images/donkeykong.jpg"/><b>Donkey Kong</b>
</div>
```

And the javascript:

```
<script>
  function getMyID(inputId){
    var game = inputId;
    var gameId = 'flash/' + inputId + '.swf';

    document.getElementById('currentgame').src = gameId;
  }
</script>
```

I'm pretty new to javascript so this is all I have managed to figure out, thanks.